# Only receive messages with specific attributes in SQS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-sqs

I have a .Net Core Web API application that uploads files on s3 bucket whenever a person uploads something on the app. The app sends messages to amazon SQS from s3 whenever a file is uploaded. The problem is, I want to only send (from s3) or receive messages (in SQS) for specific files, not all of them. Is there a way I can filter the messages using specific attributes?

Please upload a code snippet with the answer if possible. I will appreciate the help!

Comment: One option is to send the notification to an AWS Lambda function, and have it filter the messages, and only send desired ones to the SQS queue. Or, have all messages go to SQS and have the code that consumes the message check whether it is for an applicable file (so, filter in the consumer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filtering message at SQS level, better to filter notification at S3.

- Save those image with specicial prefix that will suppose to send notification
- Set SQS as target
- Cost-effective than process SQS attribute filter

By doing you will also saving compute cost and SQS cost as only relevant messages will be sent to SQS when prefix matched.

[image]

[Configuring notifications with object key name filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)